# Numpy on VScode Windows 11

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

So basically I am just starting out coding and I need to install numpy on my computer and I want to have in on VScode cause that is my editor of choice. I have noticed though that unless I am in the specific folder in which I made the virtual environment for numpy I can't access the numpy module. Is there a way that I can just have it on my computer as a whole or will I have to create a virtual environment for every library for every project I do?

Comment: You can just open a terminal and run the command `pip install numpy`, then it is installed globally.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to use a different virtual environment for every project because other projects may require different versions of a package.

Installing numpy is easy just use the command pip to install numpy in the terminal in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured the environment variables, you can execute `pip install numpy` in the terminal where the virtual environment is not activated to install `numpy` for the global environment. Then select the interpreter with `numpy` installed in vscode.

You can also set the interpreter path where the `numpy` package is installed as the vscode default python interpreter. Add the following configuration in *settings.json*

```json
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path\to\python.exe",
```

and select **Use Python from `python.defaultInterpreterPath` setting** in the **Select Interpreter** panel.

[image]